# How to get metadata from SimpleExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I am working on music app where i play music from url. I am new to ExoPlayer, i don't know how to get metadata information from ExoPlayer. I want to show metadata info in notification.

I have used `MediaSource` for passing source to ExoPlayer like this :

```
MediaSource mediaSources = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse("***.mp3"),
                dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
```

Any possibility to get metadata from ExoPlayer?

Answer (score 0):

With version 2.1 you can listen metadata. Just add

> public void addMetadataOutput(MetadataOutput listener)

to SimpleExoPlayer.